# How can I add a variable to the -description command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've written a tidy little script that creates 3 AD groups from a keyboard input and then assigns them to the correct OUs, so far so good. But i would like to add another input to create the group description
i have added another variable $location which takes the keyboard input but it doesnot work. I have tried this to end my line -description "grants rights to" + $location
any help most appreciated

Comment: Hi Phil - This should be possible, please [edit] your question and show the logic/code you are using that works for you needs but giving you trouble updating the description property after masking out anything sensitive with generic values, etc. so folks can see what work you have already done. It should be something like such though basically `Set-ADUser -Identity userxyz -Description "My Test Description"`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP managed to fix their problem

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by creating two variables:

- one a text message
- the other an input

Then I just added them `-description $name$location`.
This is my first time here so in future I will remember to add my script before asking.